# Gmail CSS convention

Tags: css

I've just looked at Gmail source, and I'm surprised the way they name id / class name.

**This is just a curious what do them mean ?**
[image]

Comment: Having a hard time reading those names...

Comment: @Klaus Open image in new tab (using Chrome) which should provide actual size or go directly to the image itself http://i.imgur.com/RR4LI.png

Comment: @Aaron ~ As long as Klaus has been around here, I think the joke was on the fact that it's been minified.

Comment: @drachenstern Was a sizing assumption as the image at least for my eyes is not visible in the default context...;/

Comment: @Aaron ~ It's not visible for anyone in the default context

Comment: @drachenstern Unless CTRL++ is being heavily used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gmail uses a minifier on it's CSS and javascript - that's why you get such bizarre names for classes, ids, javascript variables, etc.

If I'm not mistaken they likely use something like [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) for building the site, and then compile it down to the form you're seeing.

Comment: Presumably to save bandwidth?

Comment: @Nathan - for bandwidth, and with the added benefit of obfuscation!

Comment: I doubt it was for intentional obfuscation.

Answer (score 4):

Knowing how much the Google guys care about caching, bandwidth and such, I suppose these names are just short random IDs generated by an automated CSS minifier.

Answer (score 1):

The class names by themselves have no *meaning* in English.  They have quite a bit of meaning to the browser, since they are tied to CSS declarations.

They also seem to **indicate** that Gmail is using a grid based system and a CSS minifier, for what that is worth.